# E1 in 6 membered rings

Tags: organic-chemistry

According to my lecturer, if the geometry prevents planarization of the C-centre than an E1 is impossible. As chair and boat are the only stable conformations of a 6 membered ring of carbons, does this mean that such a ring can never undergo an E1?

Furthermore, why must the C-centre be planar for E1? I guess it allows for maximal stabilization by hyperconjugation?

Comment: The chair and boat are conformations of *cyclohexane*. But cyclohexane isn't the only compount with a six-membered ring of carbons. For example, cyclohexene exists...

Comment: Well, a ring can twist into an unstable conformation..

Comment: Bridgehead atoms can't. You need to think about *product* - cyclohexene is perfectly reasonable. Double bond at bridgehead, not really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer to your question, without any complications, is pretty simple

Whatever can be forced into planarity in order to bear the $sp^2$ carbocation will undergo $E1$, this can be easily achieved in cyclohexane, as it can easily have a twisted conformation which is relatively less stable, but yet can bear the carbocation. Same is not the case with bridgehead carbons.